# Is a chakra a supernatural invisible thing, or a symbol for something natural?

Tags: yoga, tantra, science, chakras

I'm western and skeptical. I was born in a spiritualist family where the concept of chakras were used as being a part of spiritual body. But for spiritualists the term "spiritual" is something supernatural and always unfalsifiable. I'm not satisfied with this way of thinking.

Recently I started to study old religions like Buddhism, Hinduism and indigenous beliefs, and I see that all of them have a naturalistic approach to explain how things work, like the body, nature, the cosmos, etc. That approach fits in my mind.

I have not found a description of supernatural reality in Hinduism. Occultism is usually used in esoteric beliefs. I know chakras are common in tantric practices and tantra is esoteric and I know chakras are not tantra-specific.

Were chakras in ancient India something occult and supernatural like the theosophists propose in the West, or just an abstract representation of something present in nature which the ancients didn't know scientifically?

Comment: Is it a question or an opinion? :)

Comment: Sun is a chakra, moon is a chakra, earth is a chakra, stars are chakras, planets are chakras and so are you

Answer (score 3):

I think by 'Chakra' you mean the six chakras referred to in the yogic and tantrik scriptures.

According to the book 'Serpent Power' which in fact is based on 'Tantra-Tattva' by Sri Shivachandra Vidyanarva, the author's Guru,John Woodrof writes that the chakras are visible only to the yogis and are Supernatural and Invisible. (2nd edition, page 163-4).

According to the 'Puja-Tattva'

> When (Kundalini/PrAna-)Shakti becomes busy in creation, She remembers Her consort and feels His attraction. So he wants to return back to Him now and then. So two forces--centripetal and centrifugal---are generated in the flow of Shakti which leads to flow Her in circular path,which is the origin of the chakras.(page 47).

The Rudra-YAmala says

> If someone worship the Divine Mother without the knowledge of the spiritual meanings of the chakras, he can not wash off his sins. He can not get siddhi even in seven births. One must first know the tattva of shat-chakra-veda.(parva 21).

Reference: Satramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana, Upandrakumar Das,Vol 2,RMIC, page 971.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supernatural thing. It is present in every person but not active or peoole are not aware of it.

Chakras are esoteric principle for sure. They exist in Astral body, but have connection with physical body. If you dissect spine, you will not find any chakras.

**Chakras or Wheels**

Chakras are life energy distributing centers in the spine and sushumna (astral passage) connected to the glandular system of the physical body through endocrine glands, neuro physical activities are controlled by chakras. There are numerous chakras, major and minor. Most important chakras are 7 or sometimes nine, some of them are in spine and some in the skull. They rotate clockwise and anti-clockwise half way through and that rotation is so fast that the petals are seen as a chakra or wheel and during the half way through rotation chakras receives and disperses life energy Speed of the chakras differ, as one evolves spiritually the speed increases. Awakening of kundalini is closely linked to the refinement of chakra activities. Chakras do have a close connection in the control or activation of brain functions and mental activities. They are also connected to the bio-magnetic field around the body which is "Aura".

Chakras are energy dispersing centers or minor powerhouses whereas the cerebellum is the main power house in the brain.

You can find more detailed description of Chakras in the books of Sir John Woodrofe, books published by Theosophical society.

I would like to suggest one specific book on the [chakras](http://www.anandgholap.net/Chakras-CWL.pdf) THE CHAKRAS
A MONOGRAP BY C. W. LEADBEATER
with ten colour illustrations

Comment: I beliver you need to activate each chackra through specific practice, either by mantra chanting or yoga..  Sir John Woodrofe book is helpful